# I lost my residency card. Can I travel using the refugee passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, greece, refugees

I lost my Greek residency card while I am in Belgium. Can I travel using the Greek Refugee Passport?

> **comment from OP**:
> My residency is valid, but my residency card was in my wallet and stolen from me

Comment: You lost your residency card, or your actual residency?

Comment: Is this what you understand as a 'Greek Blue Passport'?: [Council of the European Union - PRADO - GRC-JO-03001](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/GRC-JO-03001/index.html): *Travel document pursuant to the Convention of 28 July 1951, issued to persons having **refugee status** in Greece.*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And where do you wish to travel to?

Comment: My residency is valid, but my residency card was in my wallet and stolen from me

Comment: Have you reported the loss to the police? They should issue an confirmation that can be shown when required.

Comment: I have informed the police to issue a new residence permit. I need 3 months. I want to travel for necessity and I do not have the blue travel document.

Comment: When you say "Blue Passport" and "Blue Travel Document," do you refer to a Greek Blue Card? The Greek _Blue Card_ is a work authorization document or permit. It is not a passport, and does not identify or authorize you for travel purposes.

Comment: It is not a blue card, it is a temporary passport for 5 years given to refugees who cannot go to the embassy of their country of origin and obtain a passport.

Comment: Whether you can travel using a 1951 Convention Refugee Travel Document issued by Greece — what I now think you refer to as a "Blue Passport" — will depend upon the law of Greece, the identity(ies) of the countries to which you want to travel, and the identity of your country of origin: even though you are a refugee from that country, countries to which you seek admission sometimes have different rules for granting or denying admission that depend upon the identity of the refugee's country of origin.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to make some assumptions here.  Please let me know if any are incorrect.

Given:

- your Greek residence permit was in your wallet when it was stolen in Belgium
- you have a refugee travel document issued by Greece

Assumed:

- you are still in Belgium
- you want to travel to Greece without leaving the Schengen area

Answer:

You can travel to Greece with your refugee passport alone.

More detail:

As noted in the comments, you might need a visa to enter non-Schengen countries, so if you plan to leave the Schengen area (including in transit) you will need to check the visa requirements.  As far as the Schengen area is concerned, your Greek refugee travel document is sufficient because it establishes under international law that Greece has granted you the right to return to Greece.